# JMeter GUI - Can't drag and drop to last element in hierarchy

Tags: swing, user-interface, drag-and-drop, jmeter

JMeter GUI (Swing) has drag and drop abilities,

The problem is that sometimes I need to drag component to last of the hierarchy (e.g. last request in Thread Group)
and the GUI seems to allow it but when releasing the mouse key nothing happens.

For example below I can't drop Request 3 to its location as the last component, I must make 2 drag and drop requests: Request 1 and 2 to make the order 1,2,3.

[image]

Is it a swing limitation or JMeter have a reason to disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced same problem many times. I think that it is a Swing problem. Just drop component to parent element. The component will be dropped as the last. In your example drop Request 3 to Thread group.